# How to write functions that only operate on characters within a rectangular-region?

Tags: region, rectangle

I've found emacs has support for rectangular selection, however I didn't see references to API's for only operating on contents within the rectangle mark.

How would this be acomplished?

Take this simple interactive function as an example.

How could this function properly take rectangular regions into account?

```el
(defun reverse-line-or-region ()
  "Example function that reverses the line or region."
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg nil)
        (end nil))
    (cond
     ((region-active-p)
      (setq beg (region-beginning))
      (setq end (region-end)))
     (t
      (setq beg (line-beginning-position))
      (setq end (line-end-position))))

    ;; Shrink the selection (avoids issues with newlines at end of the region).
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char end)
      (skip-chars-backward "[:space:]")
      (setq end (point))

      (goto-char beg)
      (skip-chars-forward "[:space:]")
      (setq beg (point)))

    (let* ((str-prev (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))
           ;; Just an example, could be some other operation.
           (str-next (reverse str-prev)))
      (delete-region beg end)
      (goto-char beg)
      (insert str-next))))
```

Comment: Emacs doesn't have rectangular selection, only rectangular copy-paste. So kill rectangle, yank into temporary buffer, operate, then again kill and yank?

Comment: Ah, I assumed it would be supported as evil-mode in emacs can do this.

Comment: I wonder if `rectangle-mark-mode` would help. And maybe check the evil sources to see how they do it?